# Can I replace a lower resolution DAC with a higher resolution DAC with similar characteristics

Tags: dac

My first application requires a 10-bit and a 12-bit Voltage output Quad DAC. I have another application which requires two 12-bit Quad DACs

I have chosen matching DACs MAX5714/MAX5715 which costs 2.85/4.27$ a piece. Here is the data sheet http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/256/MAX5713-MAX5715-472601.pdf. Characteristics of both DAC seem similar

To save some costs, I am thinking of buying just two MAX5715 DAC's instead of three DACs(two MAX5715 DAC + one MAX5714 DAC).

Can I use a higher resolution 12-bit MAX5715 where 10-bit MAX5714 is needed?

Comment: What makes you think you couldn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem.

Looking at Table 1, you could set B5 and B4 to zero to get "10-bit" performance.

[image]

If eveything works out as expected you could use the 10bit DAC in the final design.